# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning while using assert.doesNotReject

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, assert

```
const assert = require('assert');

main = () => {
    try {
        const toTest = async () => {
            return Promise.reject('ERROR'); // or throw 'Error';
        }
        assert.doesNotReject(toTest, TypeError);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

main();
```

After copying to file and run it. It prompts out

```
(node:3056) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ERROR
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:3056) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:3056) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

It just gives the warnings. Anyway to fix this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because from Node v7 if you don't handle a rejected promise you would get the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` warning.
It's expected that you handle all promise rejections with a `.catch(...)` or if you are using `async/await` then you handle it with a `try...catch` block.
This is to ensure that you don't ignore any errors that happen in your code, in a future Node version this warning would actually be an error.

Your code is giving this warning because `toTest` is returning a Promise rejection but it's not being handled.
When you call `assert.doesNotReject(toTest, TypeError);` it awaits the `toTest` promise and checks that the promise is not rejected.
Since the awaited promise returns a rejection the assertion will catch it and reject it again and since the rejected promise isn't handled it will give a warning saying `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

> Using assert.doesNotReject() is actually not useful because there is little benefit in catching a rejection and then rejecting it again.

Source: https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_doesnotreject_asyncfn_error_message

Comment: The toTest() returns a rejection and isn't handled, but assert.doesNotReject() should feed a rejected promise due to the test purpose

Comment: That's because ```assert.doesNotReject``` catches the rejection and rejects it again. Let me update the answer with this information

Answer (score 0):

I found out that assert.doesNotReject returns a promise
so instead of 'assert.doesNotReject(...)', it should be 'await assert.doesNotReject(...)'